# "Better go home" vs "better to go home"

Tags: colloquial-language

Do both mean the same? Or maybe one version is correct and the other one is incorrect?

Example sentence:

> It's getting late. Better (to) go home.

(This is colloquial speech.)

Another similar situation:

> He's going to arrive late. Better (to) text him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's getting late. Better go home.

The meaning is elliptical. It is an admonition: I had better go home, or you had better go home, or we had better go home.  Context would probably make clear which it was.

With the marked infinitive:

> He's probably left the office. Better **to text** him than email him. I don't think he has an email app on his phone.

the statement means "it would be better to text him". It's not an admonition but an assertion.

Comment: I see. So it's not a grammar issue. It's about what I want to express.